# Find availability in multiple calendars with relation using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, gaps-and-islands, mariadb-10.4

I own something that I frequently rent out. It consists of several parts. It can either be rented part by part, or as a whole. If one part is rented out, you wont be able to rent it as *a whole*.

An example can be that I rent out a car. This car has tires which also are for rent. You can choose to rent the car with the tires («the whole»), or just rent a tire. However you won't be able to rent the car («the whole») if one or more tires are rented out.

I visualize it as a hierarchy.

```
         Whole
    _______|_______
   |               |
 Part 1           Part 2
```

I have used one Google Calendar for «the whole» thing and separate calendars for each containing part. This works, but it's tiresome and I want to be able to just send a link to those who's interested - where they can see what is available.

So I made a database (mariadb 10.4) that is plain simple, having two tables:

```
# tbl: part
| id | parent_id | name   |
```

The column `parent_id` simply refrences another row in the same table, here's an example of data.

```
| 1  | NULL      | Car    |
| 2  | 1         | Tire 1 |
| 3  | 1         | Tire 2 |
```

Then the following table to store dates when each part is `booked` (+ example data).

```
# tbl: booking
| id | part_id | booked_from | booked_until |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1       | 2021-07-31  | 2021-08-03   |
| 2  | 2       | 2021-08-03  | 2021-08-07   |
| 3  | 3       | 2021-08-04  | 2021-08-06   |
| 4  | 3       | 2021-08-09  | 2021-08-10   |
```

Out from this we know that the car itself is booked from `2021-07-31` - `2021-08-03`, but its only bookable from `2021-08-06` since two of the tires are rented out for this period (They can however be rented out at the same time as they're not strictly related). But just until the `2021-08-09` since a tire is booked again.

What I'm looking for is a query to get a list of dates when something is available. From the `pars`-table I'm able to find out which parts are related and that's not my biggest problem - I guess, since can use something like this when querying availability for:

- The car: `part_id IN(1,2,3)`
- Tire 1: `part_id IN(1,2)`
- Tire 3: `part_id IN(1,3)`

My problem is (simply?) how I can orchestrate a query that returns only the dates when something is available, especially for the car when dates can overlap.

E.g results for the car

```
SELECT 
  `booked_until` AS `available-from`, 
  `booked_from` as `available-until`
FROM 
  booking
/** some JOIN magic? **
WHERE part_id IN(1,2,3)
```

E.g for **tire 1** would be the same but with `part_id IN(1,2)` as `tire 2 (id: 3)` isn't directly related with `tire 1`.

Both should respectively return:

```
# car
| available-from | available-until |
------------------------------------
| NULL           | 2021-07-31      |
| 2021-08-06     | 2021-08-09      |
| 2021-08-10     | NULL            |
```

```
# tire 1
| available-from | available-until |
------------------------------------
| NULL           | 2021-07-31      |
| 2021-08-07     | NULL            |
```

Where the `NULL`-values just says there's nothing booked before or ahead. E.g this tire is available `from now` until the `2021-07-31` and from `2021-08-07` until the last day earth exists.

Hope this makes sense - and that someone is able to help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using mysql 8? else such tress have limited fubctionality

Comment: Hi, I'm using MariaDB `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.18-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

Comment: then take a look at recursive ctes

Comment: Thanks. Had a look into it, but whatever I call the `WITH` statement (e.g `cte_availability`) it fails with `#1146 - Table '<db>.cte_availability' doesn't exists`.

Comment: can you make a dbfiddle and we can see what might the error, without code .....

Comment: Hi, thanks for prompt replys. Here's a fiddle with data similiar to the post: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bcWAtmH1CWh6KUex9nF8NJ/1

Comment: and your sql code?

Comment: Oh, you wrote «without code», so I didn't add it. Just made the table plus data from the post.. I can add it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234211/discussion-between-joachim-and-nbk).

Comment: You should be using [a fiddle that match your server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=8351ea7cb97e93040642558b59595b5e).

Comment: I added a solution below without recursive ctes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's my attempt.

So, if I understand correctly, additionally to the information given explicitly in the table, there is implicit unavailability for the units. So I first retrieved this explicitly:

```
select unit_id, entry_start, entry_end 
  from unit_calendar_entry
union
select p.id, u.entry_start, u.entry_end
 from unit p
 join unit_calendar_entry u
   on  p.parent_unit_id = u.unit_id
union
select p.parent_unit_id as unit_id, u.entry_start, u.entry_end 
 from unit p
 join unit_calendar_entry u
   on p.id = u.unit_id
  and p.parent_unit_id is not null
order by unit_id, entry_start;
```

- the first `select` just gets the entries already in the table
- the second one adds entries for the car, since it can be considered booked if either of its tires is booked
- the third one adds entries for the tires, since they can be considered booked if the car is booked

Result:

```
unit_id     entry_start           entry_end
----------------------------------------------------
1          2021-07-31 00:00:00   2021-08-03 00:00:00
1          2021-08-03 00:00:00   2021-08-07 00:00:00
1          2021-08-04 00:00:00   2021-08-06 00:00:00
1          2021-08-09 00:00:00   2021-08-10 00:00:00
2          2021-07-31 00:00:00   2021-08-03 00:00:00
2          2021-08-03 00:00:00   2021-08-07 00:00:00
3          2021-07-31 00:00:00   2021-08-03 00:00:00
3          2021-08-04 00:00:00   2021-08-06 00:00:00
3          2021-08-09 00:00:00   2021-08-10 00:00:00
```

Based on that, there is a *gaps-and-islands* problem to solve in order to group adjacent/overlapping timespans. You can use two queries to mark the entries that belong together, [like in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56960761/14015737). If we call the above query `subtab`, the according statement is

```
select c.*, sum(case when prev_end < entry_start then 1 else 0 end) over (order by unit_id, entry_start) as grouping   
         from (
              select subtab.*, max(entry_end) over (partition by unit_id order by entry_start rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_end 
                from subtab
              ) c
```

- The inner query gets the previous end for each row.
- The outer one assigns a grouping id that (within each `unit_id`) identifies all entries belonging to a continuous block (aka an *island*).

Result:

```
unit_id entry_start          entry_end            prev_end             grouping
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       2021-07-31 00:00:00  2021-08-03 00:00:00  (null)               0
1       2021-08-03 00:00:00  2021-08-07 00:00:00  2021-08-03 00:00:00  0
1       2021-08-04 00:00:00  2021-08-06 00:00:00  2021-08-07 00:00:00  0
1       2021-08-09 00:00:00  2021-08-10 00:00:00  2021-08-07 00:00:00  1
2       2021-07-31 00:00:00  2021-08-03 00:00:00  (null)               1
2       2021-08-03 00:00:00  2021-08-07 00:00:00  2021-08-03 00:00:00  1
3       2021-07-31 00:00:00  2021-08-03 00:00:00  (null)               1
3       2021-08-04 00:00:00  2021-08-06 00:00:00  2021-08-03 00:00:00  2
3       2021-08-09 00:00:00  2021-08-10 00:00:00  2021-08-06 00:00:00  3
```

From this (let's call it `tab`), you can either obtain the unavailable timespans by grouping on `unit_id` and `grouping` (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56960761/14015737) or db<>fiddle below) or calculate the free times as follows:

```
select distinct unit_id
              , NULLIF((min(ifnull(prev_end,'1000-01-01')) over (partition by unit_id, grouping)),'1000-01-01') as available_from
              , min(entry_start) over (partition by unit_id, grouping) as available_til
   from tab
union 
select distinct unit_id
                , max(entry_end) over (partition by unit_id) as available_from
                , null as available_til
 from tab
order by unit_id, available_from
```

- the first query gets `available_from` as the minimum of the `prev_end` for each `unit_id`/`grouping`. In order to get `NULL` values from `MIN()`, I used a workaround similar to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32240382/14015737).
- the second query adds a row for each `unit_id` with the maximum `entry_end` as start and `NULL` as end

Result:

```
unit_id  available_from         available_til
---------------------------------------------------
1        (null)                 2021-07-31 00:00:00
1        2021-08-07 00:00:00    2021-08-09 00:00:00
1        2021-08-10 00:00:00    (null)
2        (null)                 2021-07-31 00:00:00
2        2021-08-07 00:00:00    (null)
3        (null)                 2021-07-31 00:00:00
3        2021-08-03 00:00:00    2021-08-04 00:00:00
3        2021-08-06 00:00:00    2021-08-09 00:00:00
3        2021-08-10 00:00:00    (null)
```

Putting it all together in one query:

```
with tab as (
            select c.*, sum(case when prev_end < entry_start then 1 else 0 end) over (order by unit_id, entry_start) as grouping   
              from (
                   select d.*, max(entry_end) over (partition by unit_id order by entry_start rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_end 
                     from (
                      select unit_id, entry_start, entry_end 
                        from unit_calendar_entry
                      union
                      select p.id, u.entry_start, u.entry_end
                       from unit p
                       join unit_calendar_entry u
                         on p.parent_unit_id = u.unit_id
                      union
                      select p.parent_unit_id as unit_id, u.entry_start, u.entry_end 
                       from unit p
                       join unit_calendar_entry u
                         on p.id = u.unit_id
                        and p.parent_unit_id is not null
                          ) d
                   ) c
            ) 
 select distinct unit_id, NULLIF((min(ifnull(prev_end,'1000-01-01')) over (partition by unit_id, grouping)),'1000-01-01') as available_from, min(entry_start) over (partition by unit_id, grouping) as available_til
   from tab
   union 
  select distinct unit_id, max(entry_end) over (partition by unit_id) as available_from, null as available_til
   from tab
 order by unit_id, available_from
```

See also [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=fdcadf020312884aa82b0efb7730b77e).

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you so much** for this - it's is extremely helpful of you.

As this query is very complex for me to actually understand fully, I would like to ask

1. How do I select only the result for `unit_id = 1`? I tried to use a where statement on the outer query, but without any effect. It would be enough to return the result for unit 1, where all calendars intersect, when specifying `WHERE unit_id IN(1,2,3)` (that would be the lines returned for unit 1 in the db<>fiddle).

```
unit_id  available_from         available_til
---------------------------------------------------
1        (null)                 2021-07-31 00:00:00
1        2021-08-07 00:00:00    2021-08-09 00:00:00
1        2021-08-10 00:00:00    (null)
```

2. How do I limit the result for a date-range, lets say between date `2021-08-01 - 2021-08-30`.

Again, thank you so much!

EDIT:
What if I add «bolts» (to mount the tires) to the equation, giving the hierarchy another level. Would this solution still work?

```
                                    Whole
                               _______|_______
                              |               |
                            Part 1           Part 2
                        ______|____          ...
                        |          |
                     Bolt 1 .... Bolt N
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had to extend the solution a little bit more. Added another table that keeps specific data for every entry for each item. E.g for what time it need to be returned and the time it takes to prepare «the ting» back to its original state. This is just an approximation and not so important, but it should restrict anyone to come collect it before a certain time. :)

So tables looks like this now:

```
# tbl: property_unit (former: part)
| id | parent_id | identifier   |

# tbl: property_unit_calendar (NEW)
| id | property_unit_id | return_by | preparation_time |

# tbl: property_unit_calendar_entry (former: booking)
| id | calendar_id | entry_start | entry_end |
```

This doesn't affect the current query much, as the time in column `return_by` and `preparation_time` from table `property_unit_calendar` is applied to the datetime-fields in `property_unit_calendar_entry` when booked.

Adopted the code and added this relation. It seems to work fine - (again, thank you so much).

The updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=eb10ec55c84914a714d673368e6f929f)

Now I'm struggling to find out how I should reduce the result to match the actual `unit` that I'm checking availability for. Should I add for each of the `tab`-selects? Like this

```
FROM tab
WHERE property_unit = 8
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
  ...
FROM tab
WHERE property_unit = 8
```

The other thing I'm struggling with is how I can reduce the result to a certain frame, for instance between dates, from a date or until a date.

Main problem isn't how to get results between/from/until the dates but if a booking is ahead in time of before the timeframe, it would give me `NULL` either way in the first and last row - which should indicate that it's available for "unpredictable past/future" (which might not be correct).

So.... would it be best to add an additional query for the NULL's to check if there are bookings before or after the frame?

Hope I explained this good enough. So much dependencies to think of!

Thanks!

Comment: Realized I could use `WHERE property_unit_id = 8` on the `d`-selector/alias within the `tab`-with, to only get results for this unit. Now what only is left is a way to make sure it doesn't say  that it's available for the whole futere when a date range, start or end is set.

Comment: I could probably also put the date test just after the `ìd`-test, but I guess it would use a lot more computer power instead of doing some magic in the inner query (`d`)?